# Jquery/Javascript: Local storage plugin wont allow me to store an index, why? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, cookies, local-storage

**NOTE:** I just figured out that this will make it work: `$.Storage.set("whichp", ""+myindex)`, adding the quotes, then a plus, then the variable. why wont it work with just the variable like this: `$.Storage.set("whichp", myindex)`? If I even just remove the quotes and leave the plus, like so: `$.Storage.set("whichp", myindex)` it wont work either.

I'm using a [Jquery plugin](http://sites.google.com/site/daveschindler/jquery-html5-storage-plugin) that stores local data, if your browser has the capability. If not, it stores a cookie instead. On the developers site he says:

> Names and values should be strings.
>   Some browsers may accept non-string
>   values, but not all do.

The format to set data is:

```
$.Storage.set("name", "value")
```

and to get the value:

```
$.Storage.get("name")
```

I thought I could set a variable, then insert that var as the value, like this:

```
var myindex = $(this).index()
$.Storage.set("whichp",  mystring)
```

but it's not working... if I were to do this though:

```
var mynote = "this is a test"
$.Storage.set("whichp",  mynote)
```

then it will work.... I don't understand why it wont allow me to put the index into storage...

my full code for this click event is below.

```
$('P').click(function () {
        var myindex = $(this).index()
    if (!$.Storage.get("whichp")) {
        $.Storage.set("whichp",  myindex)           
    } else {
        alert($.Storage.get("whichp"))  
    }
});
```

[Jquery plugin](http://sites.google.com/site/daveschindler/jquery-html5-storage-plugin)

It just doesn't set it in local storage/cookie, it's just empty.

Comment: After setting `var myindex = $(this).index()` have you tried `alert`-ing the variable, and the `$(this).index()`? Also: note the missing semi-colon following `.index()`.

Comment: yeah, alerting it tells me the index. I just figured out that this will make it work: `$.Storage.set("whichp",  ""+myindex)`, adding the quotes, then a plus, then the variable. why wont it work with just the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Since you have figured out the error and the way you have described it, I can only assume that it is happening because the Storage plugin won't store a number. basically myindex is a number when it is returned by the

```
$(this).index()
```

call. However doing  a "" + myindex converts it into a string. To check the theory, try this

```
 $.Storage.set("whichp",  myindex.toString())
```

You are trying to store a variable mystring which isn't defined anywhere. Should you not be storing variable myindex instead?

This should work

```
$('P').click(function () {
        var myindex = $(this).index()
    if (!$.Storage.get("whichp")) {
        $.Storage.set("whichp",  myindex)          
    } else {
        alert($.Storage.get("whichp"))  
    }
});
```

Comment: Good catch; I'm not sure that it's not a typo though. :)

Comment: ah sorry that's a typo i put in when here at stackoverflow, it's correct in my code. I found out how to fix the problem, it's at the top of my question, but I don't know why it works like it does.... ?

Comment: I modified my original answer to explain why ""+myindex probably works!

Comment: ahhhh! awesome! i still suck at javascript, so i just learned something new, neeaaaattt. thanks man. Works perfectly now.